# Convert a char type stored in an array to an int variable

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I'm currently working on a project and I need to do something very specific. I need to store a value in a `database` of sorts using a char array, but I also need to store the value of a multiplication in the last slot of it and I have no idea how to do this. Casting the char variable and multiplying it seems to store garbage on the `int` as I get values way off the range it should be. Another suggestion I tried was using `memset()` to manually set the value but I don't quite know how to go about that.

Here's my code

```
int form_fill(int room_ID, char database[rooms * floors * req_data][20]) {
    printf ("Enter the first name\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets (database[room_ID]);
    printf ("Enter the second name\n");
    gets (database[room_ID + 1]);
    printf ("Enter the third name\n");
    gets (database[room_ID + 2]);
    printf ("How many days will the guest stay?\n");
}
```

Ideally the days the user inputs will be stored in `database[room_ID + 3]` as a `char` and multiplied by another variable declared earlier as global and the result stored, as a `char`, in `database[room_ID + 4]`.
Anyone got any solutions for this?

ps. I know using gets is unsafe, but that's what the teacher asked so I have to.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);`--- undefined behaviour.

Comment: [FYR] `gets()` is **evil**, use `fgets()`.

Comment: "I know using gets is unsafe, but that's what the teacher asked so I have to." -- *Always question the teachers, they may discover new things*

Comment: Tell your teacher to join SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement is not very clear, but as of now, a generic way to achieve what you want is to

1. Take the input from user for "How many days will the guest stay?" using `fgets()`.
2. Convert the *string* input to `int` by using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) and store in a temporary `int` variable.
3. Multiply that value with your global `char`.
4. *Print* the result to `database[room_ID+4]` using [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).